# Updating nested array's field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema

```
const RoomSchema = mongoose.Schema({
title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
body: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
author: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
resource: {
    type: String
},
posts: {
    type: Array,
    default: []
},
url: {
    type: String
},
created_at: {
    type: String,
    required: true
}});
```

Field 'posts' is another document in my db, defined by the following schema:

```
const PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({
header: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
body: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
author: {
   username: {type:String, required: true},
   _id: {type:String, required:true}
},
room: {
    type: String,
    required: true
}});
```

So, I'm trying to create a query that would update fields of certain post inside posts array inside room. I've already tried suggested here, thought without results. I would appreciate any help on the subject

```
 Room.update({ '_id': roomId, 'posts._id': postId },
    { $set: { 'posts.$.header': newHeader, 'posts.$.body': newBody } },
    callback);
```

Comment: The field `posts` doesn't have an element called `id`, it's an Array, not an Object. What you are looking for is a `find` for getting the data, then a `forEach`over the `posts` and then an `update` with the new `posts` Array.

Comment: So, there is no way to perform this from mongo shell?

Comment: Also, why is there a `room` key in the posts? If you have all posts with all their data inside of the room, why reference it at all?

Comment: Do you absolutely need to do it from mongodb's shell? You never mentioned that but tagged it as JS

Comment: I was just wondering if this could be done with only some complex mongoose query, without intermediary forEach.

Comment: Could be, I haven't worked with mdb for more than a few months. The Javascript approach does work though, I use it myself, just never used the shell for anything

Comment: Your query looks almost alright. But (@LucaKiebel is very much right here) how would you want to identify a post? There is no `id` field on your post subdocument. Iterating, however, is not required in this case and inefficient compared to your suggested straight `update` approach - you just need to filter on the right fields... If you add some sample data, it will be easier for people to point you in the right direction. Also, there really are heaps of examples for this specific problem on StackOverflow already...

Comment: Your "schema" is wrong. `posts: { "type": [PostSchema], "default": undefined }`. This allows your data to be "embedded" just like the code you are trying to copy from is expecting. If you think you want a different "collection" for `Post`, then it's not the "array" you need to update, but the items in the "collection" instead. Everything else here is just "chatter" and that is essentially the only issue. Work out which you have and make the appropriate corrections.

Comment: I figured I'd rather store only ids of posts, rather than entire posts. Thus, I've gotten rid of these nested monsters. Thank you all for help